# scraping images from a web page using selenium python?

Tags: python, image, selenium, screen-scraping

Some one on another platform asks for some one to **scrape** images from a web sit. The idea is that the images load in the same page. I couldn't find a way except for loading all the image in the page using selenium then extract every image url then open each image in a new tab and download it; but this is very resource consuming, the images in some cases go over 200003
I am new to scraping and my web design background is alitle; Is there is abetter teqniuque to **scrape** the images.
note: I am not doing it for the money; it is only practicing new teqniuques.

https://generated.photos/faces/natural/front-facing/young-adult/white-race/brown-hair/short/joy/female/brown-eyes

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AOA Muhammad Here is the code you can follow the code and can extract all the images.

```
#import modules
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#define headers
headers = {
    'authority': 'api.generated.photos',
    'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^Google',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'authorization': 'API-Key Cph30qkLrdJDkjW-THCeyA',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36',
    'origin': 'https://generated.photos',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://generated.photos/',
    'accept-language': 'en-PK,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'cookie': 'gp_session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVG86HVJhY2s6OlNlc3Npb246OlNlc3Npb25JZAY6D0BwdWJsaWNfaWRJIkViMzUzYjQ3MTYyOTNjMzdkOTE2OTU4MzZkNzAxNjUyODY1MjU3NTExOTNlNzhmYjY2NDMyOTY1MDEyNjkxMDZiBjsARkkiDGNhcnRfaWQGOwBGSSIdNjA3YTg0YTdjN2VjMzEwMDBjZDY3ZGU3BjsAVA^%^3D^%^3D--038eee55b343dcdd77021c6b3494a8111809032d; _ga=GA1.2.1963701744.1618642096; _gid=GA1.2.180857723.1618642096; _gat=1',
}

#define the filters
filters = {
    'order_by': 'latest',
    'page': '1',
    'per_page': '30',
    'face': 'natural',
    'head_pose': 'front-facing',
    'age': 'young-adult',
    'ethnicity': 'white',
    'hair_color': 'brown',
    'hair_length': 'short',
    'emotion':'joy',
    'gender':'female',
    'eye_color': 'brown',
}

#Now requests to website

image_url = []
#start loop for pagination
for i in range(1,687):       
    api = f"https://api.generated.photos/api/frontend/v1/images?order_by=latest&page={i}&per_page=30&face=natural&head_pose=front-facing&age=young-adult&ethnicity=white&hair_color=brown&hair_length=short&emotion=joy&gender=female&eye_color=brown"
    response = requests.get(api, headers=headers)
    #loads the response to json
    json_res = json.loads(response.content)        
    image = json_res['images']
    for url in image:
        image_url.append(url['thumb_url'])


#Download the image
for url in image_url:      
    img_content = requests.get(url).content
    with open('Image.jpg','wb') as fh:
        fh.write(img_content)
```

**P:S
Keep in mind this will take a lot of time, So you can change the range like (1,4) if you're doing it just for practice.**

Comment: Thanks Adnan Zafar, is there is an article explaning how the general idea for cases like this, i mean getting the response in json it will realy help.

Comment: And can i ask about some thing else; i tried to multithreading the process on my machine and it runs ok; but when i try to run it on google co-lab it dosen't work and it shows no errors and no output eve a simple print, i searched but i am stuck, i can't run multithreading on google co-lab.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is not answer writing website.But getting images is simple.
1.Import the modules [`requests`,`BeautifulSoup`]

2.Get the source of the webpage.

3.Find the `div` tag which holds the images[optional step]

4.get the `img` tags from the above `div` tag
5. get the `src` attribute from img tags.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get('https://generated.photos/faces/natural/front-facing/young-adult/white-race/brown-hair/short/joy/female/brown-eyes')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
di=soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'grid-photos'})
im=di.find_all('img')
links=[i['src'] for i in im]
links
```

Comment: thanks for answerin; the code you wrote is to scrap only 30 links, how about trying the whole 20673 links